# Line with same height as list

Tags: wordpress, html-lists, line

As you can see in picture 1, I  have an `<ul>` list, created by the wordpress "Display Posts Shortcode" Plugin.

I want to have a vertical line in between the images and the text (see picture 2).

I have no idea how i could solve that problem.

pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIA73.jpg

This is the website: [here](http://tgv-beilstein-aktive.de/news)

It would be really nice if you have an idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: You would have to change the output HTML of the plugin. In order to achieve this, it's best when you contact the developer of the shortcode/posts plugin. He can give you exact advice, and will propably know some filters, hooks and actions you can use to change this

Comment: He does not answer :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions to this. Since this site doesn't seem to be responsive and the image column width appears to be fixed my easiest solution would be to...

1. Create an image the width of your line.  Looks like 3px by 3px red square would work. I'll name it red3x3.png and place it on the images folder.
2. Add the following lines to you .display-posts-listing rule at line 442 on your style.css file:

   `.display-posts-listing {
       list-style: none;
       display: inline-block;
       float: right;
       width: 100%;
       /* add following 4 lines */
       background-image: url(/bilder/red3x3.png);
       background-repeat: repeat-y;
       background-size: 1%;
       background-position-x: 220px;
   }`

Again, here are several other solutions but I think this one is easier and safe enough.

Comment: its not responisve YET :/ ... and an other problem is: if there is an other news article, it will be show under the other ones, so the line has to have variable height somehow.

Comment: This solution takes that into consideration.  It will extend and cover all articles.  Have you implemented my solution yet?  For responsiveness you'll need to add CSS rules on the other media queries accordingly.  Basically changing background-position-x: 220px; to a lesser number.